# spring boot application main method unit test with mockito

Tags: unit-testing, spring-boot, mockito

I'm very new to unit testing and mockito. How can write a unit test for the code below.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MyApplication {
    public static void main(String[] argv) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyApplication.class);
    }
}
```

Comment: There's nothing to test here. Move along.

Comment: and nothing to mock !

Comment: and techncially tested via other Spring Boot tests, such as `SpringBootTest`, `MockMvc` etc which cannot function (easily) without it

Answer (score -1, accepted):

From my experience, you usually don't test the one-line `main` method of a `@SpringBootApplication` annotated class. The only logic you have there is a static call to `run` from `SpringApplication` class.

If you **really** want to unit test that, then the only possibility is to use [PowerMock](https://github.com/powermock/powermock). Mockito itself doesn't offer the possibility to mock static methods, while PowerMock allows you to do that. You could refer to [this PowerMock wiki page](https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/Mockito).

But seriously, as JB Nizet said: nothing to test here, really. Especially that the recommendation is to use [Spring Initializr](https://start.spring.io/) which auto-generates it for you and I believe that in most cases - you shouldn't really be touching that.